# SQL: How do I fix this error? ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 18: END $GO$;

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am trying to create a function in PostgreSQL as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcGetGameID( parm_p1 CHAR(8), parm_p2 CHAR(8)) RETURNS INT 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $GO$
DECLARE 
  gid INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT g_id INTO gid FROM tblGames
    WHERE p1_id = parm_p1 AND p2_id = parm_p2;

   IF gid IS NULL THEN 
       RETURN NULL;
   ELSE IF parm_p1 > parm_p2 THEN 
       RETURN (-1)*gid;
   ELSE 
       RETURN gid;
   END IF;
                
END $GO$;
```

When I try to run this, I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 18: END $GO$;
             ^
```

I've tried looking at multiple posts on here, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When I try END; without $GO$, the console seems to want me to continue the code.

Comment: See [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html). It should be `... END; $GO$.

Comment: The $GO$ being without a semicolon? Same issue. Console wants the code to continue. And with a semicolon, the error becomes:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 18: END; $GO$;
Pointing towards the semicolon at END.

Comment: It should be `ELSEIF`  or `ELSIF` not `ELSE IF` and at the end `... END: $GO$;` or `... END: $GO$;`. See [Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). I also reformatted the code in the question to make it easier to find the issue.

Comment: It was the ELSIF bit that was causing it. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: You also don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A simple `language sql` function will do when you move the `IF` into the SELECT as a CASE expression.